# Cannot convert value of type '[EClass]' to expected argument type 'EClass'

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I'm calling this function

```
func addMarker(place:EClass) {

    guard let coordinates = place.location  else {
        return
    }

    self.destination = coordinates
    // clear current marker
    marker.map = nil

    marker.position = coordinates
    marker.title = place.name
    marker.map = mapView
    mapView.selectedMarker = marker

    }
```

in my viewDidLoad

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
         locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
         let srt = sortedArray

     for category in categories! {
             addMarker(place: srt)
        }
 }
```

also with a cycle, because i want to add in the mapView a marker to each place of my array `sortedArray`, but of course i'm getting the error "Cannot convert value of type '[EClass]' to expected argument type 'EClass'". How can i solve this problem?

Comment: If you want to add each element of `sortedArray` then why do you iterate over `categories!` (whatever that is)?

Comment: you're feeding it an array `[EClass]`when it wants a single element `EClass`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call `addMarker` with each member of your `sortedArray`, you can do this:

```
srt.forEach { addMarker(place: $0) }
```

Comment: You should mention that this would be used instead of the current `for` loop.

Comment: ok the error seems to be fix but is not showing the markers in the mapView

Comment: You're not showing nearly enough code to help diagnose this, unfortunately.